# Jquery datepicker start date from 2 days later

Tags: jquery, datetime, picker

i'm trying to prepare a reservation form and reservations have to start from 2 days later i mean customers can't select date for tomorrow.

```
$(function() {
$( "#date" ).datepicker({  maxDate: '0'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myDate = new Date();
$("#date").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(myDate.getTime() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)  
});
```

This works fine. Only dates from the 27th of November will be clickable now.

## JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/op989L9z/